# Trim secrets manager ARN in cloudformation

Tags: node.js, aws-cloudformation

I have a piece of cloudformation code that output the secrets manager ARN that goes like this

```
  MyRDSInstanceRotationSecret:
    Description: Arn of the secret manager of the MySQL
    Value: !Ref MyRDSInstanceRotationSecret
    Export:
      Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'MyRDSInstanceRotationSecret' ] ]
```

But what I get from the value is the full arn of `arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-4:660123456789:secret:oJoirj-BqGEoSmVOqTX-wg2H5I`. My node application do not need the whole ARN, just the last part which contains the secrets name will do. I just need the last component `oJoirj-BqGEoSmVOqTX-wg2H5I`. is there a way to trim strings on cloudformation? Or I have to trim it on nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to **split Arn** based on `:`:

```
 !Select [6, !Split [':', !Ref MyRDSInstanceRotationSecret]]
```

I assume that `MyRDSInstanceRotationSecret` is `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret`.